# Как выключить VM на Proxmox

Tags: proxmox

У меня зависла ВМ, к ней никак не подключиться. Пробую нажать кнопку выключения, перезагрузки, остановки и паузы, но выдаёт ошибку:

TASK ERROR: can't lock file '/var/lock/qemu-server/lock-100.conf' - got timeout

Можно ли выключить её?

Answer (score 0):

Обычно решается командой:
qm stop 100
А так же команды: [CLI Usage Examples](https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/chapter-qm.html#_cli_usage_examples)
А так же можно посмотреть и здесь:
[Proxmox can’t shutdown/stop virtual machine](https://dannyda.com/2020/05/11/how-to-fix-proxmox-pve-cant-lock-file-var-lock-qemu-server-lock-xxx-conf-got-timeout-proxmox-cant-shutdown-virtual-machine/)

Comment: А где можно это ввести?

Answer (score 0):

Вводится в Shell на самой ноде (самом сервере) пример ВМ 100.

rm -f /var/lock/qemu-server/lock-100.conf

qm unlock 100

qm stop 100

так же, можно использовать

```
ps aux | grep "/usr/bin/kvm -id 100"
```

в выводе находится ID процесса (например 192837):

```
kill -9 192837
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]